# GMap Module issue

Tags: 7, google-maps

I am using the [GMap Module](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) for Drupal 7 along with [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location), with Node Locations enabled.

I have added a simple location field in my article content type, and enabled the location block to be shown in main content type.

During the creation of an article, when I enter the location values as text fields (e.g. countries, cities) without any latitude and longitudes, the map is not displayed on the article node page.

However, if I do enter some latitude and longitude values, either manually or using Google Maps, then the map is shown in the article node.

Does anybody have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think this is to do with the Geocoding settings, i.e. resolving the location from an address/postcode.

I played with the modules a week or so ago and found the Geocoding for the UK was not possible.

Try looking in the configuration options for the Location module, in particular the Geocoding tab. You'll see that the United Kingdom has no settings available so in my case I'll have to resort to requiring the user to use the map itself to specify the location.

Comment: it was a geocoding issue in the configuration for Locations module.